# HTML - how to do something like frameset?

Tags: html, menu, frameset

I want to build a basic website using HTML, CSS only for learning myself:
- top part is the club banner/logo
- left side bar shows list of years, eg.:
2010
2011
2012
2013
2014
2015
2016

- the rest (right part) under the banner depends on the year the user clicked on

So I want to keep the banner (top) and the left side bar do not need to refresh everytime  user click on the year.
It only shows the corresponding content of the year clicked, on the right part (for example the events held in the year).
Is frameset the only way to do?

Answer (score 0):

frameset tag is not supported in HTML5. so for better browser support you may use iframes 
My suggestion is go with iframes otherwise you can use object and embed like so

```
<object data="http://www.example.net" width="600" height="400">
<embed src="http://www.example.net" width="600" height="400"> </embed>
Error: Embedded data could not be displayed.
```